# What is the difference between Super User and Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between Super User and Stack Overflow?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4836/what-is-the-difference-betweensuper-user-and-stack-overflow)

I've discovered that there is http://stackoverflow.com and http://superuser.com and perhaps many other similar sites.

What are the differences between these sites?

Comment: We are much nicer over here at SuperUser!

Answer (score 15):

Super User is tailored for personal computing questions - hardware and software problems you'd face in a home or SOHO environment. Server Fault covers computers in a professional environment. Stack Overflow covers coding.

Your first port of call for such things would be the FAQ for each site. If you have further questions on the norms for a site, you need to use the meta sites

Answer (score 10):

Superuser is about using computers. Stackoverflow is about programming computers.

Comment: Being a *really* bad nitpicker, I have to caveat my own answer: the two often overlap. Just now I answered a question on Superuser about deleting large numbers of files. Part of my answer was adapted from a complicated shell command that I found in an answer on Stackoverflow.

Comment: A surprisingly simple distinction, I like this. I agree, it is a little bit simple and not all-encompassing definition, but good way to put it! +1

Comment: Thanks. I write technical docs for a living. Surprisingly simple distinctions are how I pay the rent.

Answer (score 9):

[Super User](http://superuser.com), [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), and [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) are the first three sites in the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) network, and are often referred to as "the trilogy." The Stack Exchange network now consists of over 80 sites in topics varying from cooking to bicycling to different languages. They all use the same software, have the same general guidelines and standards, and are all interrelated at a higher level. However, each site decides its own scope and what sorts of questions it handles.

If you'd like to check out other sites in the network and see which ones might interest you, check out the main [Stack Exchange site listing](http://stackexchange.com/sites), and read the [About page](http://stackexchange.com/about) for more info about the network's origins and philosophy. The [Stack Exchange blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/) also has a lot of history on the evolution of the network.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a site who's purpose is to flesh out and gauge interest in creating new Stack Exchange sites.  [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com)

> Area 51 is the Stack Exchange Network staging zone, where users come
>   together to build new Q&A sites. New site ideas are proposed,
>   discussed, and the best go on to beta.

It's a pretty interesting process if you're curious :)